# Android open application from QR Code

Tags: android, qr-code

I'm really curious about is there anyway that I can generate a QR Code which contains maybe an `URI` and after the scan the qr code reader can start my application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I register my application on Android to handle a "type" of QR Code ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972279/how-can-i-register-my-application-on-android-to-handle-a-type-of-qr-code)

Answer (score 1):

If you make an intent filter for the URI you put into your QR-code, you'll be fine I guess.

Just put the correct scheme (and host/path) in the `data` part, and you'll get the option to start with your app. Ofcourse, if another app filters for this data, the user can choose that one too, so be sure to be completely unique (that won't be possible with "http" obviously on account of browsers), or to catch that behaviour in the URI.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how should the URI must look. Because I've tried with something like this : `<data android:scheme="myApp" android:host="org.hardartcore.myApp" android:path="/"/>` and the qr code scanner tells me that it can't open it.

Comment: you could start with using the http scheme and an url, that should work (both in a qr-code, and it is easy to test you've got your intent correct)

Comment: so you suggest i create a qr code with something like this : `http://myApp://org.hardartcore.myApp`. Did I understand you correct or I'm missing something?

Comment: No, I suggest you create a QR code with `http://somesite.tld/somepath` just to see if you have the intent correct. Your browser also wants to open this link, but ignore that. If you have that working, then you can check how/if it works with another scheme. Don't add schemes to scheme, double scheme doesn't make sense. There is no real need for your package-name to be in there, just some sort of unique code, as you're catching intents, not directing apps